# JL equivalent in 8051 assembly

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm looking for JL (jump if less) equivalent in 8051 assembly. The closest solution I figured out was

```
CJNE A,#42,DUMMY
DUMMY: JC IS_LESS ; jump to IS_LESS if A<42
```

Is there any more elegant way? I mean without that DUMMY label. I'd like to perform something like CMP instruction. I could simply SUB, but I'd like just non-destructive test of the value.

Comment: You can get rid of the label if you use the appropriate symbol for the current address in your assembler, ie. something like `cjne a,#42,$+3` and you can stick that into a macro called `cmp`.

Comment: That would be great, but EdSim51 simulator cries about syntax error (unknown label $+3). Does it work in other compilers?

Comment: Other assemblers use `.` not `$` maybe try that or consult the manual :)

Comment: `as31` uses `*`, so `cjne a, #42, *+3` works there. `edsim` doesn't seem to have macro support either, otherwise you could just emit the instruction bytes from a macro too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [the manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0509.pdf) properly, `CJNE`'s syntax in this case is `CJNE A,#data,rel`, where *rel* is referenced as

> Signed (two’s complement) 8-bit offset byte. Used by SJMP and all conditional jumps. Range is -128 to +127 **bytes relative to first byte of the following instruction**.

Therefore, "`JL`" instruction could be coded as

```
CJNE A, #42, 0 ; 0 = do not jump
JC IS_LESS     ; jump to IS_LESS if A<42
```

Comment: It's weird that in Proteus 8.15 VSM debugging with AT89C51, the program counter change to 0 instead. It should be relative, why it is absolute? What went wrong?